# Fetching Data from second tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to open a toplevel window and then close it, but fetch the input:

```
def popupDeadline():
    newWindow = Toplevel()
    newWindow.geometry("290x100+300+300")
    newWindow.configure(bg='#ffffff')   
    newWindow.resizable(height=False, width=False)
    labelFrame = Label(newWindow, text="Enter Deadline (YYYY-MM-DD)")
    labelFrame.place(x=50, y=10)
    labelFrame.configure(bg='#ffffff') 
    deadlined=StringVar()
    d1=Entry(newWindow,textvariable=deadlined)
    d1.config(width=40)
    d1.place(x=50, y=30, width=200, height=20)
    btn = Button(newWindow, text="Enter", command=save_quit) 
    btn.place(x=50, y=50, width=100, height=20)
```

And:

```
def save_quit():
    deadline = deadlined.get()
```

This doesn't work, because deadlined is not defined. How can I do this? Like I said, the idea is to open a popup window for a input, then close it but keep the input.

Comment: try saying `global deadlined` inside of your `popupDeadline()`

Comment: and i think you misstyped it here _"because deadline is not defined."_ did you mean `deadlined` instead of `deadline`

Comment: Yes, you are right. deadlined is not defined.

Comment: It works now, thank you. I made the mistake to define it global in the mainloop, outside the function.

Comment: Ive added an answer to make it more clear, do let me know

Comment: @mn_wy thanks for accepting my answer as best!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to your problem is simple like this:

**Step 1. Store the value inside `Entry` in a variable Eg:-**

```
variable_name = entry_name.get()
```

**Step 2. Put the above code in a function that can be triggered when the button is clicked**

```
def function_name():
    global variable_name
    variable_name = entry_name.get()
```

But here's a change though:
Assign global to the variable you use to store contents (Not just inside the function, but outside the function away from the `Toplevel()` declaration)

If that doesn't work either, please let me know what the error is.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The problem is that `deadlined` is a local variable so it is inaccessible from other functions.

Comment: @BryanOakley  I meant I was just giving a general example by `variable_name` If you declare the variable which is `deadlined` in mn_wy's case outside of all functions, as well as declare global to it in the function and where it was declared then it would work. By the way what's up with the downvotes?

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that your variable `deadlined` is a local variable, meaning its available on inside your function. So as to use it inside of other function you will have to say `global deadlined` so that now the variable can be accessed in the `global` scope.

```
def popupDeadline():
    global deadlined
....
```

[More on global and local variables](https://funprogramming.org/50-What-are-global-and-local-variables.html)

Hope it helped you. Do let me know if any errors.

Cheers